# how to set a SITE variable for localhost using PHP

Tags: php, localhost

A contract programmer altered our site by adding a SITE variable and now when running it on local host it gives the following error:

"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - 
    http://localhost/test2016/%3C?=SITE?%3Ecss/screen_layout_medium.css"

We do not know how to overcome this problem. We have tried all 5 options below.

```
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

defined('SITE') ? null : define('SITE', "");
defined('SITE') ? null : define('SITE', __DIR__);
defined('SITE') ? null : define('SITE', __DIR__.DS);
defined('SITE') ? null : define('SITE', dirname(__FILE__));
defined('SITE') ? null : define('SITE', DS);
```

I have posted this because we are having a little difficulty getting an answer from him.

Comment: What **should** the URL be

Comment: Why not ask the contractor

Comment: the url should be http://localhost/test2016/css/screen_layout_medium.css" The contractor is overseas.

Answer (score 0):

The `SITE` constant is probably defined in the local version as well. The problem is that the value of this constant is set to work in your production environment.

What you will have to do is to locate the `SITE` constant and change it to work with your local environment.

Another option is possible using a runkit extension.

```
// Redefine SITE constant
runkit_constant_redefine('SITE', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

In order to help you out better, I will need some more information on both the server directory structure and the localhost directory structure.

You can find the PHP Manual entry to `runkit_constant_redefine` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-constant-redefine.php)

#### Edit

What could help is to dump the `SITE` constant and check it's value before trying to redefine it.

```
var_dump(SITE);
```

Comment: Thank you for you help but the localhost that was used by the contract programmer was overseas and we do not have access to it. We do not have have a SITE constant.

Comment: Guessing what might be in the constant is going to be hard. If you do not know what to define, it's hard to define it. What can help though is executing a `pwd` and `ls -lh` command on your website directory and posting the results here.

Comment: Thank you again, the constant should be empty, see my comment above.

Comment: Is there a `.htaccess` file in your website directory?